# Reading 2N2222 BJT datasheet

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi

I know this question was asked before, But couldn't understand properly the datasheet reading.

I would like to control `water pump` via `RPI`.

Wanted to make sure Im reading the datasheet correctly + Im connecting everything properly.

[image]

So if I understand correctly, on the worst case, the water pump will need 6v. so the calculations will be according to `Ipump(max)`

```
Ipump(max) = 1.8w/6v = 300mA
Ipump(min) = 0.6w/4v = 150mA
```

According to `2N2222` [data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF), figure 11:

[image]

When `Ic=300mA`, `Vbe(sat)=0.9v` and `hfe=10`.

So:

```
Ib = Ic/hfe -> 300m/10 = 30mA
R1 = (Vrpi - Vbe)/Ib -> (3.3-0.9)/30m = 80ohm
```

In order to make sure the water pump will get the current it needs, we will limit `Ic` to higher value:

```
R1=50ohm
Ib=(3.3-0.9)/50= 48mA
Ic=Ib*hfe= 48m*10 = 480mA
```

So `R1=50ohm`

Wanted to ask :

```
1. Do I read the `hfe` correctly? is it the right value to make sure the saturation?
2. There is a need to connect a diode in parallel to the water pump? resistor in series to the water pump?
```

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Problem is, Raspberry Pi can only source 16mA from its GPIOs. You won't be able to properly bias the transistor with a direct connection. A logic-level MOSFET would be a better choice than a 2N2222 - the VN2222 at 3.3V can pass more than 1A (be careful of power dissipation, though)

Comment: To your other points, your maths seem OK. And yes, any sort of switched inductive load generally needs a clamp diode to protect against inductive kickback when the switch opens.

Comment: Where did you get the hfe=10?

Comment: @evildemonic The hfe=10 is from the plot, it is the ratio Ic/Ib that was **forced** to keep the NPN in saturation. So it is not the hfe from the transistor itself when it is operating in linear mode.

Comment: In my opinion you're "pushing" things to their limits a bit too much, the assumed hfe = 10 is quite low resulting in that you need a lot of base current. Actually more than an Rpi should be delivering. It can be done I guess if you limit the current from the Rpi to about 10 mA so then hfe = Ic/Ib would be 30 (=300 mA / 10 mA) and getting a bit close to the lower limit of the NPN's own hfe. I agree with Adam that an **NMOS** would be a much better choice. I would use an AO3400 they're cheap and have a very low on resistance. They're small though, SMD only.

Comment: The peak current for a pump may be considerably higher than the average current, both during starting and due to torque changes during motor rotation. That could result in the motor stalling with a large voltage across the transistor, which would subsequently suffer damage. Unless you want to measure the actual start/peak run currents I would suggest allowing for a few A, with a logic-level MOSFET such as AO3400A. You should also put a flyback diode across the motor.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Good suggestion. lol

Comment: I would consider a 2N2222 to be marginal for a collector current of 300mA -- it's much better to use a transistor rated for around twice what you intend to use.  And the comment about the pump pulling more current at start-up is spot on.

Comment: The graphs on most datasheets are for a device with "typical' spec's. Your device might have minimum or maximum spec's that you should calculate for or you might nave many or intermittent failures. The text in a datasheet shows minimum and maximum spec's.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  Bimpelrekkie Thank you, is it seems like good solution. do you know if it can come with bigger size? it too small to solder it (hobby project)